# Manipulate each Row of a Dataframe containing Lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("list1", "list2"))
df$Content <- list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "A"))
```

For each row in "Content", I would like to first Remove duplicates, then find all rows containing certain elements, for example "A", and it would return both row 1 and 2.

I've tried using **duplicate()** with **apply()** but it seems to be finding duplicates on the list level, as in, does c("A", "B", "C") match c("A", "B", "A") instead of finding duplicates within each list.

Similarly, I'm having trouble identifying the presence of a specific element in the list, instead of trying to match things to the list as a whole.

The only thing I could think of is using a **for loop**, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list` elements, return the `unique` elements, then `filter` the rows of the dataset where there is 'A' in the 'Content'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(Content  = map(Content, unique)) %>%
   filter(map_lgl(Content, ~ 'A' %in% .x))
#    id Content
#1 list1 A, B, C
#2 list2    A, B
```

---

Or another option is to `unnest` the `list` column, do a `group_by` `filter` on the `distinct` rows and then `condense` (from `devel` version of `dplyr`) or `summarise` into a `list` column

```
df %>%
    unnest(c(Content)) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter('A' %in% Content) %>%
    condense(Content)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Rowwise:  id
#  id    Content  
#   <fct> <list>   
#1 list1 <chr [3]>
```

2 list2